# How to add a dropdown link to an existing responsive navigation menu

Tags: html, css, navigation, dropdown

I have an existing responsive nav menu that I want to add a sub-menu to (actually it is just one link under one of the top menu items). Sounds like it should be very EASY, but I cannot figure it out. As soon as I add the link, it either ends up just below the top item (making the whole nav grow down with it) or displaying "none" makes it disappear and not come back on hover. Is there a simple way to do this with CSS only? I hope my question is clear enough. I will include my necessary code. If you give me code, please tell me where to put it. I am a Newbie. Thanks so much for any help.

```
HTML:

<nav><a href="index.html">
      <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo-text.png" alt="CBS Stuctures, Inc."></div>
      </a>
      <label for="drop" class="toggle">MENU</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="completed.html">COMPLETED PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="structures.html">STRUCTURES</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="video-presentation.html">Video Presentation</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="new-products.html">NEW PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


CSS:

nav {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}
nav:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.toggle, [id=drop] {
    display: none;
}
nav a:hover {
    color: #70E4FC;
}
nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
nav ul li ul:hover{
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
#logo {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
}
    nav ul{
        width: 100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        float: none;
        background-color: rgba(16,70,56,1.00);
    }
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px;
     background-color:rgba(11,51,41,1.00);
}
    nav ul li:hover{
          background-color:#0F4739;
        }
    .toggle + a, .menu{
        display: none;
    }
    .toggle{
        display:block;
        background-color: #333333;
        padding: 14px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        cursor: pointer;  
    }
    .toggle:hover {
        background-color:#515151;
    }
    [id^=drop]:checked + ul{
        display: block;
    }
    }
```

[image: Without hover]

[image: With hover]

Comment: you mean you want to show the child menu on hover?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a **`hover selector`** on **`child ul`** inside **`li`** of a parent **`ul`**

```
ul li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

To apply it to specific element, you must add a **`class`** to your child ul:

```
ul li:hover ul.childul {display: block;}
```

check working example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgzNKe)

Comment: can you add screenshots

Comment: Thank you "fmsthird".  I got it to the point you are, but when I hover over it, it displaces the top nav item and makes the whole navbar expand down instead of just dropping down. Does that make sense?

Comment: Added screenshots.

Comment: Yes! That works. There is just one more little thing. In the mobile view, the "Video Presentation" link covers the link that comes after it. Is there a way to push the links that come after or below the dropdown?

Comment: yeah just use @media query to apply specific css

Comment: Thanks again "fmsthird", you really helped me! I did figure out my last issue with the mobile version. Changed Position: absolute to relative. Check this "Answered"! :O)